Custom Menu Not Displaying in Google Sheets Add-on After Deployment
The problem:
I am developing a Google Sheets add-on using Google Apps Script. The goal is to create a custom menu in Google Sheets that allows users to apply specific formatting options. The add-on has been successfully deployed, but the custom menu does not appear in the Sheets interface after installation.
What I’ve Done:

Developed the Script:
function onOpen(e) {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Tools')
        .addItem('Apply General Formatting', 'ApplyGeneralFormatting')
        .addToUi();
}

function ApplyGeneralFormatting() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    range.setVerticalAlignment("middle");
    range.setWrap(true);
}


Configured the Manifest:
{
  "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "SheetFormatter",
      "logoUrl": "https://example.com/logo.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onOpen"
      }
    }
  }
}


Published the Add-on:

The add-on is visible in the Google Workspace Marketplace.
Installed it successfully in my account.


Troubleshooting:

The add-on appears as installed under "Extensions > Add-ons > Manage Add-ons."
When I test the onOpen() function in the Apps Script editor, it logs the following error:
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.





What I Need Help With:

Why is the custom menu not appearing in Google Sheets after the add-on is installed?
How can I debug the onOpen() function to identify the issue?
Is there a specific deployment configuration I might have missed?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your attention and guidance. Following your instructions, I have modified the manifest to the following:
{
  "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ]
}

When I test the deployment, the option for "Editor Add-on" appears, and during the test, the menu is successfully generated as expected.

However, when trying to perform the actual deployment, I do not see the option for "Editor Add-on." Instead, the options available to me are:

App da Web (Web App)
Executável da API (API Executable)
Complemento (Add-on)
Biblioteca (Library)

I am unsure how to proceed from here. Do I need to create and configure a project in the Google Cloud Platform to deploy this properly, or is there another step I might be missing?
Once again, thank you for your attention and help!

It's important to note that there are two types of addons:

Editor addons
Workspace addons

Editor addons create menus and run from there. Workspace addons create homepages and cards. Triggers like onOpen run automatically on open when it is a editor addon. While for workspace adfons, you need to click the button on right panel.  As you've seen,  it's not possible for a homepageTriggered function to interact with the Ui.  It seems you've created a workspace addon, while you're looking for functionality of editor addons. To convert to editor addons,

Remove addOns object from manifest
In Cloud console, remove Workspace addon from App Integrations.

Related:

How to show instruction with image after install google workspace extension?

